# Amplifying Current from 0-20mA to 3A

Tags: current, amplifier, plc

I would like to drive a pump with a PLC. The PLC generates analog output signal of 0-10V with 0-20mA and the pump runs at the same voltage but 3A current. Is there any solution to this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: do you wnt to run the pump at a single speed (on/off control) or do you need variable speed control? is the pump powered by DC or AC  what voltage and how many phases etc?

Comment: The plan is to control the speed of the pump at variable speed. The analog output of the PLC is generated by PID controller and as I mentioned the output of PLC is 0-10V with 0-20mA. I noticed that the max power of PLC that can be delivered is 0.2W and this is not enough to run the pump.Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: The two things you mention have almost nothing in common.  The PLC 20mA current loop is a signal loop. Buy a 20mA loop Rx and build an appropriate driver for your motor. 20mA loops are almost always for analog signals (not ON/OFF) so this implies speed control. If you require speed control, build the motor driver and then interface to the 20mA loop Rx.

Comment: Jack the whole purpose of this project is to be able to control the speed of the pump and variable velocity.

Comment: So the "RUN" current is 3 amps. What is the maximum START current?

Answer (score 0):

Buy a VFD or other appropriate motor driver that can take a 0-10 V analog input.

You don't want to "amplify the current" if you can get away with it. For driving a motor, it's far more efficient to use PWM or similar. All you need to do is take that 0-10 V analog signal and use that to control the PWM duty cycle. This can be done with analog circuitry or with a microcontroller. You'll need to follow that up with a high current output stage, such as a power transistor or H bridge. You can probably buy a box off the shelf somewhere that does all that.